# Is scientific evidence ever allowed when answering a question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

There are Christian denominations that claim no contradiction to science or the scientific method.  This begs the question, is scientific evidence allowed when answering a question?  Or should it be excluded?

Comment: I'd argue that a Christian HAS to believe that God created science, and therefore, discussions of science and Christianity *should* be good friends.  However, I'll also be the first to admit that Christians can make horrible arguments for and against science.  The Christian community has a history as coming off as sounding ignorant and archaic, especially with regards to science.

Comment: @NickDeVore, as an atheist, thanks for your very honest answer.  I find that I can not discuss science in the context of religion because it's often met with either ignorance or suspicion.  Not all the time but often.

Answer (score 7):

Scientific evidence is of course allowed where it is appropriate. For example, it's reasonable in answer to a question about wine in the Bible to point out that wine is preserved better than grape juice.

However it's worth restating that the site is about Christianity. It assumes a Christian viewpoint. If you start answering questions with 'science says Christianity is untrue' then your answers are going to be unwanted. The same would be true if you said the same about history, philosophy or sociology.

Comment: But some Christian traditions use science to defend their arguments.  You're proposing that they're antithetical.  A "Christian" viewpoint can still be scientific, don't you agree?

Comment: I'm not proposing that they are antithetical, in fact the reverse.

Comment: "Scientific evidence is of course allowed where it is appropriate." Some might take the position that it's _always_ appropriate.

Comment: Example of where it's appropriate: When quoting an established Christian apologetics group that is citing scientific evidence. example: According to this linked answer from Answers in Genesis, (quote containing scientific info here)...

Comment: Why do you need to quote Christian apologetics on matters of science?   You do understand there's no such thing as muslim science, christian geometry, jewish physics, etc.

Comment: @rpeg An example of of where it is inappropriate: In a question about [transubstantiation](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/541/what-do-catholics-mean-when-they-talk-about-the-real-presence-in-the-eucharist), I'm not looking for a scientific analysis of the communion wafer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to exclude it provided that it's relevant to a well supported answer. However, most denominations do not hold science to the same standard to which they hold scripture and their own confessions and so it should probably not be a *primary* source as science is rarely a source of doctrine or dogma.

Comment: There's the complicating fact that many Christian groups *claim* to respect science, while clearly not actually doing so.

Comment: A commenter on the previous answer suggests that scientific evidence should only be cited from Christian sources.  I think this makes little sense.  Your thoughts on that?